# how to draw a graph in gtk3

Tags: c, graph, plot, gtk3

How to draw a graph in gtk3. I want to plot 2D scientific graph. Earlier in gtk2 GtkPlot was available but now it is deprecated in gtk3. What is the alternative to GtkPlot?
I am using gtk3 with C.

Answer (score 1):

Production ready library see [`GtkDatabox`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkdatabox/).

---

If you are going to create a widget yourself:

Basically you overwrite the default drawing handler of a `GtkDrawingArea` (which your widget is derived from. There you get a `cairo` context to draw on.

[`goatplot`](https://github.com/drahnr/goatplot) is pretty much exactly that with some candy API ontop.